# Magento 2 Customizable Options for orders not appearing using API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, custom-options, rest-api

Is there a way to get customizable options from an order to the API?

For example, this product allows a customer to enter a name on a t-shirt - 
[image]

This also appears on the admin side of the order -

[image: order information]

But this doesn't seem to appear anywhere on the API (/rest/V1/orders/xxxxxx)

Was hoping these options would be available out the box for third parties checking the API.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one is similar to the below Url in github. That can be solve your issue.

Use Search Criteria to get specifically:

Method : GET

```
/rest/V1/orders/items?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=order_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Check with below Url :

[Please Click here to find in detailed](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/946)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but for anyone running into this, my answer here might help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/313072/88690